# How do I add a number to call a specific variable in Angular? See Example

Tags: arrays, angular, variables

I have a network with nodes. Each of these nodes have a decimal number. When I click on one of those nodes I open a dialog, which should display an array of transactions from that node.
So for example: If I click on Node 1, I want `transactions` to be `this.transactionsMiner1`.
Currently I tried it with `this.transactionsMiner+nodeID`, which didn't work.
What is the easiest way to implement that?

```
 transactions: Transaction[];
 transactionsMiner1: Transaction[] = [];
 transactionsMiner2: Transaction[] = [];

dialogConfig.data = {
  sender: nodeID,
  transactions: this.transactionsMiner+nodeID,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of transactionMiners instead of individual ones.

```js
transactions: Transaction[];
 transactionsMiners: Transaction[][] = [];

dialogConfig.data = {
  sender: nodeID,
  transactions: this.transactionsMiner[nodeID],
};
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for your `transactionsMiners` and access them via your nodeID

```
transactionsMiners: Transaction[][] = [];

dialogConfig.data = {
    sender: nodeID,
    transactions: this.transactionsMiners[nodeID],
};
```